# How to match image shape in UIGestureRecognizer in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I want to make shape match app [like this](http://enapp.appvv.com/424277.html).

Please check the second image of this link.

please check [this link](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/animal-mix-match-shape-matching/id627521020?mt=8) also,
I can drag and drop image but I am unable to match the exact location and unable to fill that image with another one.

Any idea or suggestions would be highly welcome.

Comment: How to give link like this?

Comment: How have you tried matching location? And what do you mean by 'fill that image with another one'? Are you not simply overlaying or replacing views?

Comment: Sir I am new in iphone and this project is assigned to me, so I am searching and asking about this from iPhone Experts. Really no idea sir about this project.

Answer (score 1):

`//UIImageView *imageView1` (blank image with whom the image has to be matched),

`//UIImageView *imageView2` (the coloured image that has to be matched)

Take a `NSMutableArray` positionArray, now whenever you add any new blank imageview (imageview1 ) to the screen add its additional information to the MutableArray like

```
UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,100,50)];
[imageview setTag:TagValue];
[imageview setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blankMonkeyShapedImage.png"]];

//Incrementing the TagValue by one each time any blank imageview is added
TagValue++; 

NSMutableDictionary *locationDic=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[locationDic setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:imageview.tag] forKey:@"TagNumber"]; 
[locationDic setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Monkey~example"] forKey:@"ImageName"];
[locationDic setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:imageview.frame.origin.x] forKey:@"PosX"];
[locationDic setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:imageview.frame.origin.x] forKey:@"PosY"];
[locationDic setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:imageview.frame.size.width] forKey:@"SizeWidth"];
[locationDic setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:imageview.frame.size.height] forKey:@"SizeHeight"];

[self.view addSubview:imageview];

[positionArray addObject:locationDic];
```

Now whenever you add any new blank imageview you should repeat the same for it . Coming back to the `UIGestureRecognizer` selector method

```
-(void)panGestureRecognizer:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
      CGPoint translation = [gesture translationInView:self.view];

      for (int i=0 ; i<[positionArray count]; i++)
      {
          NSMutableDictionary *lctionDic=[positionArray objectAtIndexPath:i];

          float posX=[[lctionDic valueFor:@"PosX"] floatValue];
          float posY=[[lctionDic valueFor:@"PosY"] floatValue];
          float SizeWidth = [[lctionDic valueFor:@"SizeWidth"] floatValue];
          float SizeHeight = [[lctionDic valueFor:@"SizeHeight"] floatValue];


          if (translation.x >= posX && translation.x <= posX+SizeWidth &&
              translation.y >= posY && translation.y <= posX+SizeHeight )
          {
              //Condition where the dragged objects position matches any previousluy placed balnk imageview.

              if(gesture.view.tag==[[lctionDic valueFor:@"TagNumber"] intValue]) 
              {
                   NSLog(@"Matched Image's Name is : %@",[lctionDic valueForKey:@"ImageName"]);
                   break;
              }
              else
                  continue;
          }
      } 
}
```

Take special care at the time of allocating TagValues to the blank imageview and the toBeDragged imageview (both should be saem for same type of image).

Answer (score 0):

That is bit tricky.

You are coder you know which image match what shape, May be you take two imageviews one with shape and other with image..

PS: I am just giving an idea.

So may be you can keep track with tags. Add gesture recogniser to drag images, so you will come to know which shape is being dragged. Now while moving just compare center of shape with center of your image current position. Make sure that you compare range and not exact center.

Hope this much info helps you :)

Comment: Thanks aloot sir. Yes it will help me. Now I have the idea where to start. Sir do you have any tutorial link related to this project?

Comment: I dont think so you will get any sample code for this. Tricks will work

Comment: Sir I have created a demo according to you. Now I am not able to understand this line "Now while moving just compare center of shape with center of your image current position."? Sir Can you give some more suggestions please.

Comment: Now I have One Green Color View And one draggable image. I give tag also, but not able to compare tag or shape. Means if image is equal to uiview then uiview color will be red, like this.